# In Java for Undoable Edit Multiple edits and String won't split

Tags: string, split, undo, redo

So when I do an Undoable Edit, and try to create a String, it won't split/create a new line no matter what.  I have tried all the \n and newline stuff.

Comment: In what programming language? Please [edit] your question to add the relevant language.

Comment: Did you mean [`UndoableEdit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.desktop/javax/swing/undo/UndoableEdit.html).

Comment: Yes Sorry about that UndoableEdit